# What is the fastest way to append one array to another in Go?

Tags: arrays, go, append, slice

Suppose that I have arrays `A` and `B` in Go.  What is the fastest way to append all the values of `B` to `A`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Arrays](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Array_types) in Go are secondary, [*slices*](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types) are the way to go. Go provides a built-in [`append()`](http://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#append) function to append slices:

```
a := []int{1, 2, 3}
b := []int{4, 5}
a = append(a, b...)
fmt.Println(a)
```

Output:

```
[1 2 3 4 5]
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/P3ncHYQ5Fp).

**Notes:**

Arrays in Go are fixed sizes: once an array is created, you cannot increase its size so you can't append elements to it. If you would have to, you would need to allocate a new, bigger array; big enough to hold all the elements from the 2 arrays. Slices are much more flexible.

Arrays in Go are so "inflexible" that even the size of the array is part of its type so for example the array type `[2]int` is distinct from the type `[3]int` so even if you would create a helper function to add/append arrays of type `[2]int` you couldn't use that to append arrays of type `[3]int`!

Read these articles to learn more about arrays and slices:

[Go Slices: usage and internals](http://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals)

[Arrays, slices (and strings): The mechanics of 'append'](http://blog.golang.org/slices)