# What is a concise way to create a 2D slice in Go?

Tags: go, slice

I am learning Go by going through [A Tour of Go](https://go.dev/tour/moretypes/18). One of the exercises there asks me to create a 2D slice of `dy` rows and `dx` columns containing `uint8`. My current approach, which works, is this:

```
a:= make([][]uint8, dy)       // initialize a slice of dy slices
for i:=0;i<dy;i++ {
    a[i] = make([]uint8, dx)  // initialize a slice of dx unit8 in each of dy slices
}
```

I think that iterating through each slice to initialize it is too verbose. And if the slice had more dimensions, the code would become unwieldy. Is there a concise way to initialize 2D (or n-dimensional) slices in Go?

Answer (score 295, accepted):

There isn't a more concise way, what you did is the "right" way; because slices are always one-dimensional but may be composed to construct higher-dimensional objects. See this question for more details: [Go: How is two dimensional array's memory representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39561140/go-how-is-two-dimensional-arrays-memory-representation).

One thing you can simplify on it is to use the `for range` construct:

```
a := make([][]uint8, dy)
for i := range a {
    a[i] = make([]uint8, dx)
}
```

Also note that if you initialize your slice with a [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals), you get this for "free", for example:

```
a := [][]uint8{
    {0, 1, 2, 3},
    {4, 5, 6, 7},
}
fmt.Println(a) // Output is [[0 1 2 3] [4 5 6 7]]
```

Yes, this has its limits as seemingly you have to enumerate all the elements; but there are some tricks, namely you don't have to enumerate all values, only the ones that are not the [zero values](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) of the element type of the slice. For more details about this, see [Keyed items in golang array initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36302441/keyed-items-in-golang-array-initialization).

For example if you want a slice where the first 10 elements are zeros, and then follows `1` and `2`, it can be created like this:

```
b := []uint{10: 1, 2}
fmt.Println(b) // Prints [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2]
```

Also note that if you'd use [arrays](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Array_types) instead of [slices](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types), it can be created very easily:

```
c := [5][5]uint8{}
fmt.Println(c)
```

Output is:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0]]
```

In case of arrays you don't have to iterate over the "outer" array and initialize "inner" arrays, as arrays are not descriptors but values. See blog post [Arrays, slices (and strings): The mechanics of 'append'](https://blog.golang.org/slices) for more details.

Try the examples on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/YN4K-vqybs).

Comment: Since using an array simplifies the code, I'd like to do that. How does one specify that in a struct? I get `cannot use [5][2]string literal (type [5][2]string) as type [][]string in field value` when I try to assign the array to what I guess I'm telling Go is a slice.

Comment: Figured it out myself, and edited the answer to add the information.

Comment: @EricLindsey While your edit is good, I'm still going to reject it because I don't want to encourage the use of arrays just because initialization is easier. In Go, arrays are secondary, slices are the way to go. For details, see [What is the fastest way to append one array to another in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28957190/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-append-one-array-to-another-in-go/28957229#28957229) Arrays have their places too, for details, see [Why have arrays in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38645175/why-have-arrays-in-go/38645895#38645895)

Comment: fair enough, but I believe the information still has merit. What I was trying to explain with my edit was that if you need the flexibility of differing dimensions between objects then slices are the way to go. On the other hand, if your information is rigidly structured and will always be the same, then arrays are not only easier to initialize, they are also more efficient. How could I improve the edit?

Comment: @EricLindsey I see you made another edit which was already rejected by others. In your edit you were saying to use arrays to have faster element access. Note that Go optimizes many things, and this may not be the case, slices may be just as fast. For details, see [Array vs Slice: accessing speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30525184/array-vs-slice-accessing-speed).

Comment: I don't understand why the second edit was rejected. Perhaps I should start a new question, "Why have arrays in Go if you can't find information on SO about how to use them in a struct?" Thank you @icza for at least providing a reason for the first reject. In the article you linked, global arrays perform significantly better in the benchmark, and with the 1.8 optimization in the other answer on that question, they are more than three times better than slices. I'm going to give up on trying to contribute information to this answer now, since people clearly don't want it here.

Comment: I want to point out that the easy way of initializing an array has a constraint -- you can only use literal or constant number as dimensions, but not variables, otherwise it gives the error 

`non-constant array bound variable_name`

Answer (score 39):

There are two ways to use slices to create a matrix. Let's take a look at the differences between them.

First method:

```
matrix := make([][]int, n)
for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
    matrix[i] = make([]int, m)
}
```

Second method:

```
matrix := make([][]int, n)
rows := make([]int, n*m)
for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
    matrix[i] = rows[i*m : (i+1)*m]
}
```

In regards to the first method, making successive `make` calls doesn't ensure that you will end up with a contiguous matrix, so you may have the matrix divided in memory. Let's think of an example with two Go routines that could cause this:

1. The routine #0 runs `make([][]int, n)` to get allocated memory for `matrix`, getting a piece of memory from 0x000 to 0x07F.
2. Then, it starts the loop and does the first row `make([]int, m)`, getting from 0x080 to 0x0FF.
3. In the second iteration it gets preempted by the scheduler.
4. The scheduler gives the processor to routine #1 and it starts running. This one also uses `make` (for its own purposes) and gets from 0x100 to 0x17F (right next to the first row of routine #0).
5. After a while, it gets preempted and routine #0 starts running again.
6. It does the `make([]int, m)` corresponding to the second loop iteration and gets from 0x180 to 0x1FF for the second row. At this point, we already got two divided rows.

With the second method, the routine does `make([]int, n*m)` to get all the matrix allocated in a single slice, ensuring contiguity. After that, a loop is needed to update the matrix pointers to the subslices corresponding to each row.

You can play with the code shown above in the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/8gulJLAWaEe) to see the difference in the memory assigned by using both methods. Note that I used `runtime.Gosched()` only with the purpose of yielding the processor and forcing the scheduler to switch to another routine.

Which one to use? Imagine the worst case with the first method, i.e. each row is not next in memory to another row. Then, if your program iterates through the matrix elements (to read or write them), there will probably be more cache misses (hence higher latency) compared to the second method because of worse data locality. On the other hand, with the second method it may not be possible to get a single piece of memory allocated for the matrix, because of memory fragmentation (chunks spread all over the memory), even though theoretically there may be enough free memory for it.

Therefore, unless there's a lot of memory fragmentation and the matrix to be allocated is huge enough, you would always want to use the second method to get advantage of data locality.

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#slices shows a clever way to do the contiguous memory technique leveraging slice-native syntax (eg no need to explicitly calculate slice boundaries with expressions like (i+1)*m)

Comment: To avoid the risk of overlapping when using `append` the rows should have a  locked size: `matrix[i] = rows[i*m : (i+1)*m : (i+1)*m]`

Comment: @dolmen sorry for my lack of knowledge as I'm a beginner in Go. But can you please explain what is the use of the third computation in the slice operator?

Comment: @EternalObserver The third argument here specifies the capacity(`cap`) of the new slice created

Answer (score 5):

With Go 1.18 you get [generics](https://go.dev/blog/intro-generics).

Here is a function that uses generics to allow to create a 2D slice for any cell type.

```golang
func Make2D[T any](n, m int) [][]T {
    matrix := make([][]T, n)
    rows := make([]T, n*m)
    for i, startRow := 0, 0; i < n; i, startRow = i+1, startRow+m {
        endRow := startRow + m
        matrix[i] = rows[startRow:endRow:endRow]
    }
    return matrix
}
```

With that function in your toolbox, your code becomes:

```golang
a := Make2D[uint8](dy, dx)
```

You can play with [the code on the Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/K7vpVJdXdOe).

Comment: matrix := make([][]T, n)
for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
    matrix[i] = make([]T, m)
}

Comment: @echo You are making (n+1) memory allocations while I'm doing just 2.

Answer (score -3):

Here a consive way to do it:

```
value := [][]string{}{[]string{}{"A1","A2"}, []string{}{"B1", "B2"}}
```

PS.: you can change "string" to the type of element you're using in your slice.

Comment: The question was about a way to create a 2D slice of dynamic dimensions, which are only known at runtime, not compile time. Therefore this answer doesn't solve the problem.
You can take a look at the Go exercise the question is referring to: https://go.dev/tour/moretypes/18