# create two dimensional string array in golang

Tags: go

I need to create a 2 dimensional string array as shown below -

```
matrix = [['cat,'cat','cat'],['dog','dog']]
```

Code:-

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    { // using append

    var matrix [][]string
    matrix[0] = append(matrix[0],'cat')
        fmt.Println(matrix)
    }
}
```

Error:-

```
panic: runtime error: index out of range

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
    /tmp/sandbox863026592/main.go:11 +0x20
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a concise way to create a 2D slice in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39804861/what-is-a-concise-way-to-create-a-2d-slice-in-go)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a slice of slices, and the outer slice is `nil` until it's initialized:

```
matrix := make([][]string, 1)
matrix[0] = append(matrix[0],'cat')
fmt.Println(matrix)
```

Or:

```
var matrix [][]string
matrix = append(matrix, []string{"cat"})
fmt.Println(matrix)
```

Or:

```
var matrix [][]string
var row []string
row = append(row, "cat")
matrix = append(matrix, row)
```

Comment: Thanks, How do I add the same element to 2 position(for the last option given). append(matrix,row) by default adds to the first element...

Comment: @user1050619 initialize your outer matrix first (as in the first example).

Comment: `append(matrix,row)` does not add to the first element, it adds the row to the matrix.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with doing two-dimensional arrays with Go is that you have to initialise each part individually, e.g., if you have a `[][]bool`, you gotta allocate `[]([]bool)` first, and then allocate the individual `[]bool` afterwards; this is the same logic regardless of whether you're using `make()` or `append()` to perform the allocations.

In your example, the `matrix[0]` doesn't exist yet after a mere `var matrix [][]string`, hence you're getting the `index out of range` error.

For example, the code below would create another slice based on the size of an existing slice of a different type:

```
func solve(board [][]rune, …) {

    x := len(board)
    y := len(board[0])
    visited := make([][]bool, x)
    for i := range visited {
        visited[i] = make([]bool, y)
    }
…
```

If you simply want to initialise the slice based on a static array you have, you can do it directly like this, without even having to use `append()` or `make()`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    matrix := [][]string{{"cat", "cat", "cat"}, {"dog", "dog"}}
    fmt.Println(matrix)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/iWgts-m7c4u