# How to assign twoD array to slice of slice?

Tags: arrays, go, slice

In the below code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Simple array")
    arrayInt := []int{1, 2, 3, 4}
    fmt.Println(arrayInt, "\n")

    fmt.Println("Simple slice")
    sliceInt := arrayInt[:]
    fmt.Println(sliceInt, "\n")

    fmt.Println("Array of arrays")
    twoDimArray := [3][4]int{
        {1, 1, 1, 1},
        {2, 2, 2, 2},
        {3, 3, 3, 3},
    }
    fmt.Println(twoDimArray, "\n")

    fmt.Println("Array of slices")
    var arrayOfSlice [3][]int
    for i, _ := range twoDimArray {
        arrayOfSlice[i] = twoDimArray[i][:]
    }
    fmt.Println(arrayOfSlice, "\n")

    fmt.Println("Slice of arrays")
    var sliceOfArrays [][4]int
    sliceOfArrays = twoDimArray[:]
    fmt.Println(sliceOfArrays, "\n")

    fmt.Println("Slice of slices")
    var sliceOfSlice [][]int

}
```

---

`twoDimArray` need to be assigned to `sliceOfSlice` without creating underlying array(actual data) for `sliceOfSlice`

How to assign `twoDimArray` to `sliceOfSlice`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`twoDimArray` has element type `[4]int` and `sliceOfSlice` has element type `[]int`. Those types are different, so there cannot be a `sliceOfSlice` value that shares the backing array with `twoDimArray`. A new backing array is required for `twoDimArray`, but its elements may be slice values sharing the backing array with the elements of `twoDimArray`, or more specifically *having* the elements of `twoDimArray` as their backing array.

You have to use a loop and slice each array element of the outer array, there is no shorthand:

```
fmt.Println("Slice of slices")
var sliceOfSlice [][]int
sliceOfSlice = make([][]int, len(twoDimArray))
for i := range twoDimArray {
    sliceOfSlice[i] = twoDimArray[i][:]
}
fmt.Println(sliceOfSlice, "\n")
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/gSvUo32I9fm)):

```
Slice of slices
[[1 1 1 1] [2 2 2 2] [3 3 3 3]]
```

See related: [What is a concise way to create a 2D slice in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39804861/what-is-a-concise-way-to-create-a-2d-slice-in-go/39806983#39806983)

Comment: So, If I say `sliceOfSlice[0] = make([]int, 4)` then underlying array(of size 4) gets created for `sliceOfSlice[0]`. Is that correct?

Comment: @overexchange Yes, `make()` creates an array and slices it. And returns you the slice referencing the array created in it.

Comment: After `sliceOfSlice = make([][]int, 3)` , the length `len(sliceOfSlice[0])` and capacity `len(sliceOfSlice[0])` gives 0. So, assigning `twoDimArray[0][:]`  to `sliceOfSlice[0]` sets the slice descriptor(of `sliceOfSlice[0]`) with new values of len and cap. is that correct?

Comment: @overexchange `make([][]int, 3)` creates a slice whose element type is `[]int`, and it will have 3 elements, but all elements are the zero value of the element type which is `nil`. So this `make()` returns a slice which contains 3 `nil` slices. `sliceOfSlice[0] = twoDimArray[0][:]` slices `twoDimArray[0]` and assigns this slice value to `sliceOfSlice[0]`.

Comment: When you say syntax  `twoDimArray[0][:]` slices, does this syntax create a temporary slice descriptor and this temporary file descriptor becomes `sliceOfSlice[0]`. Is that correct?

Comment: @overexchange Not sure what you mean by "temporary". `twoDimArray[0][:]` is a [slice expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions) which results in a slice value (see [`reflect.SliceHeader`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#SliceHeader)) which gets assigned to `sliceOfSlice[0]`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219634/discussion-between-overexchange-and-icza).