# Initialize and access a two-dimensional array of type struct in golang

Tags: go, struct

I have struct, the structure like below:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type Data [][]struct {
    Message string `json:"message"`
    Status  string `json:"status"`
}

func main() {
    d := Data{
        {{message, "Halo"}, {status, "Active"}},
    }
    fmt.Println(d)
}
```

```sh
$ go run arr.go
# command-line-arguments
.\arr.go:12:5: undefined: message
.\arr.go:12:24: undefined: status
```

I want to get fields "Message" and "Status" to send back to the response. My question is How can I initialize the struct and accessing its fields? But I gon an error.

Comment: https://tour.golang.org/

Comment: If you are writing a single literal value, then the syntax is the same as if you were using a named struct type. If you ever want to `append` or insert any values however, I suggest you avoid the anonymous structs and just stick with the standard named types to avoid having to write the struct type out every time.

Comment: you may benefit from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39804861/what-is-a-concise-way-to-create-a-2d-slice-in-go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this may help.

Note. my example is a 2x2 dimension, you can have any dimension.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Data [][]struct {
    Message string `json:"message"`
    Status  string `json:"status"`
}

func main() {
    d := Data{
        {{"message1", "one"},{"message2", "two"}},
        {{"message3", "three"},{"message4", "four"}},
    }
    fmt.Println(d)
}
```

Output.

`[[{message1 one} {message2 two}] [{message3 three} {message4 four}]]`

Comment: Hai, Thank you in advance. If i try to make flow like this i got an error:
package main

import "fmt"

type Data [][]struct {
 Message string `json:"message"`
 Status  string `json:"status"`
}

func main() {
 d := Data{
  {{message, "Halo"}, {status, "Active"}},
 }
 fmt.Println(d)
}

Comment: the issue with "Data{ {{message, "Halo"}, {status, "Active"}}, }" is that you are creating message and status as separate instances, that's wrong. they should be initialized as one item.